# Does reveresed in Python take O(1) memory?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time, time-complexity

We can easily implement the reverse function in place using for loop. This takes O(n) time and O(1) memory as we just swap until n/2 (not sure if this is ceil or floor).

Does the `reversed` function in Python use this in place swapping approach? Thereby is `O(1)` memory?

Comment: If you mean [this `reversed()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), then all it's doing is creating an iterator, it's not creating a new container.

Answer (score 4):

`reversed` returns an *iterator*; it does not modify the original sequence, neither in-place nor by producing a new object. So it does not require more than O(1) space.

If you collect the values of the iteration, you will be creating a new container, which obviously requires space equivalent to the original.

You can use `[].reverse()` to do an in-place (O(1) space) reverse of a list.